# numpy.f2py - extension doesn't exist when source distribution is installed with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, distutils, f2py

I'm trying to wrap my head around f2py because my organization has a lot of legacy fortran code that I would like to incorporate into some newer python-based tools I'm writing. Ideally, I would package these tools either in source packages or wheels to make it easier to distribute to the rest of the organization.

I've written a small test package based on some other examples I've seen that just sums an array of floats. The package contents are included below. If I build a source distribution tarball using `py setup.py sdist`, everything looks like it works. It even looks like pip successfully installs it. However, if I open a python shell and try to import the newly installed module, I get an error on the `from fastadd import fadd` line in the initialization script saying

`AttributeError: module 'fastadd' has no attribute 'fastadd'`

So it seems like it didn't actually successfully build the f2py module. Doing some troubleshooting, if I open a powershell window in the package folder and just run

`py -m numpy.f2py -c fadd.pyf fadd.f90`

and then open a python shell in the same folder and try to `import fastadd`, I get an error, `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` (This is after I installed the Visual Studio build tools, a fix suggested on several threads). Following the advice on [this thread](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16416), changing the command to

`py -m numpy.f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 fadd.pyf fadd.f90`

will build a module file that I can successfully import and use. Okay, great.

*However*, when I change `config.add_extension` in the setup file to include the keyword argument `f2py_options=["--fcompiler=gnu95","--compiler=mingw32"]` and try to build a package distribution file with `setup.py sdist` command and then install using `py -m pip install fastadd-1.0a1.tar.gz`, I get *yet a different error* that says

`ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-c7406k03`

And now I'm completely flummoxed. Other configurations of the f2py_options either result in `setup.py` throwing an error or fail to create the extension altogether, similar to above. Using a simple string for the options gives an error, so apparently f2py_options does in fact expect a list input. I can't seem to find any good documentation on whether I'm using `f2py_options` correctly, and I have no idea why just adding that option would cause pip to not know where its info directory is. That makes **no** sense to me. I'd really appreciate some help on this one.

I'm running Python 3.7.0 32-bit, numpy 1.20.1, and pip 21.0.1 on a Windows 10 machine.

**--EDIT--**

Looking in the installation directory of the test module, I found a new wrinkle to this problem: the installation directory does not actually include any files listed in `MANIFEST`, not even the `__init__.py` file. If I copy `__init__.py` into the directory, trying to import the module gives the same `ImportError: DLL load failed` error I've been getting.

Also, inspecting the output of `py -m pip install`, it looks like `numpy.distutils` doesn't recognize `--fcompiler` or `--compiler` as valid options and just ignores them, even though `numpy.f2py` does recognize them.

**--END EDIT--**

**PACKAGE CONTENTS**:

```
+-fastadd
---__init__.py
---fadd.f90
---fadd.pyf
-MANIFEST.in
-README
-setup.py
```

`fadd.f90` has the following contents:

```
      subroutine fadd(vals,n,mysum)
        integer, intent(in) :: n 
        real*8,  intent(out):: mysum
        real*8, dimension(n), intent(in) :: vals

        mysum = sum(vals)
      end subroutine fadd
```

`fadd.pyf` has the following contents:

```
python module fastadd ! in 
    interface  ! in :fastadd
        subroutine fadd(vals,n,mysum) ! in :fastadd:fadd.f90
            real*8 dimension(n),intent(in) :: vals
            integer, optional,intent(in),check(len(vals)>=n),depend(vals) :: n=len(vals)
            real*8 intent(out) :: mysum
        end subroutine fadd
    end interface 
end python module fastadd
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
"""This is the documentation!"""

from .fastadd import fadd
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
include README
recursive-include fastadd *.f90
recursive-include fastadd *.pyf
recursive-include fastadd *.py
```

and, finally, `setup.py`:

```py
def configuration(pth=None):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration(
        'fastadd',
        top_path=pth, 
        version='1.0a1',
        author='John Doe',
        author_email='john.doe@fake-org.biz',
        url='fake-org.biz/fastadd',
        description="Testing f2py build process. Sums an arbitrary-length list of numbers.")
    config.add_extension(
        'fastadd', 
        sources=['fastadd\\fadd.pyf','fastadd\\fadd.f90']
    )
    return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration('fastadd').todict())
```

If it helps at all, the final `MANIFEST` file looks like this after the setup script is run:

```
# file GENERATED by distutils, do NOT edit
README
setup.py
C:\Users\username\Documents\Development\python_modules\fastadd\fastadd\fadd.f90
C:\Users\username\Documents\Development\python_modules\fastadd\fastadd\fadd.pyf
fastadd\__init__.py
fastadd\fadd.f90
fastadd\fadd.pyf
```